# TextView autosize cutdown content when accessibility options are changed

Tags: android, textview, accessibility

I have a very simple TextView with autosize enabled, the text font size is changed correctly until I change the device **font size (accessibility) to large or huge**, at this point the text is cut down at the bottom of the view, any workaround?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="@string/lorem"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="48sp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="28sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note that fix height is set **in order to show** how the text is cutdown when accessibility options **font size** is set
Here are some samples... 
`Default` font size:

[image: Default Text Size]

`Large` Text size:

[image: Large font size]

`Huge` font size:

[image: Huge font size]

Comment: What happens if you set the `layout_height` to something that wouldn't even fit four lines of non-scaled text (like maybe 70dp)? Does that get cropped?

Comment: Yes, the fix height of the sample code is just a way to easy reproduce the issue, is important to mention that the text ONLY gets cropped when "Font size" is changed from accessibility/Display settings

Comment: Your two statements contradict each other. If you have a 70dp tall TextView with normal font scaling, clearly four lines of text won't fit. Does the view ellipsize the text, or does the view crop the text?

Comment: Autosizing is not about how many lines of text it can fit, the idea of that is that it will pick the font size that will fit more text inside an specific text area (70dp - height in this case), which works, the problem is that when you change the font size from accessibility, which applies a multiplier to the font size, and this is not been taken into account, I'd expect the font size to be changed to a smaller size or the text to be ellipsed but not cropped

Answer (score 1):

Please change textview height to "wrap_content".

Comment: Actually this is the recommended way from the documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview):
```Note: If you set autosizing in an XML file, it is not recommended to use the value "wrap_content" for the layout_width or layout_height attributes of a TextView. It may produce unexpected results.```

Answer (score 1):

You enforced TextView height:

```
android:layout_height="150dp"
```

and this is not visible issue unless font is big enough that 4 lines take more than 150 dp to fit. You need to rethink your layout, preferably get rid of fixed height.

Comment: In this sample code I set this height just to make it clear how to reproduce the issue, of course if the height is bigger then there is more space but the key part of the issue is that this only happens when display font size (accessibility) is changed if not the size is correctly updated, for example look at "Default" in which the text is ellipsed and resized correctly, I'd expect this to happen even if display font size is changed

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue and solved by the following :

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="32dp"
```

and make constraints for start , end and top while bottom is optional .

try different minHeight also .

reference : https://dev.to/sigute/accessible-text-scaling-for-android-1ham